# Firebase auth problem in a chrome extension

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I searched almost everything trying to solve this issue without success.
In my chrome extension I use firebase for authentication with google using signInWithPopup().

It works for almost 90% of the time but for some users I get this error:

> A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or
> unreachable host) has occurred.

This is my code:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // User signed in.

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Error happens here.
```

Any idea what could be causing this error or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and managed to get rid of it by adding to **"content_security_policy"** (in manifest.json) URL to my project's ".firebaseapp.com" domain and following Google URLs:
https://apis.google.com https://www.googleapis.com https://securetoken.googleapis.com https://accounts.google.com

So in the end, **"content_security_policy"** ended up like this:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://apis.google.com https://www.googleapis.com https://securetoken.googleapis.com https://accounts.google.com https://my-project.firebaseapp.com; object-src 'self'"
```

If patching **"content_security_policy"** won't work, you can also try adding your project URLs and "https://accounts.google.com/" to **"permissions"**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I fixed it by adding `frame-src 'self' <the url which you are using as authDomain in firebase.initializeApp()>` in "content_security_policy" in manifest.json.